# How to report an issue to Developer about a bug that occurs seldom

Tags: manual-testing

I am getting an app exiting issue once in ten times.Could any one tell me how to report this issue to developer .Since i am not sure of exact step in which app is getting exited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With intermittent issues like this, I've found it helps to create the bug report as usual, but make sure that you say clearly that it's intermittent, and that you will update the bug report with more information as you have it.

If you don't have detailed logs, the next step is to turn on as much logging as you can and work the application until the crash happens, then attach the log to the bug report. It can also help to attach your config file if you have one - sometimes these things are dependent on the application settings.

Often this will be enough - but regardless at this point you have raised the problem. If you later find a way to force the crash every time, you will update the bug report with that information.

Some other things that can affect intermittent issues:

- It could be data-related. In complex software, it's not uncommon for tester data to cover more complicated scenarios than developer data.
- It could be specific to environment. The web application I test can crash the browser in some Windows XP systems with Internet Explorer 8 - but not all of them. The problem is a bug in IE8, but that doesn't make our customers any happier!
- It could be affected by system resources. I've seen large applications crash when a lot of other activity is occurring on a tester's system (which in my experience is normal).
- It could be caused by a memory leak. In this case there won't be a specific action that causes it, but if you run the application and track its memory usage you will see the memory consumed constantly increase until the application runs out of available memory and crashes in some form
- It could be the result of a prior error that isn't correctly handled. In this case, the actual error could be somewhere that gives no notification, but leaves the application in an unstable state which ultimately causes the crash.

Comment: Good answer. I have found that it's more important to report the fact that there is a bug, and to include what you do know about it, than to worry that you don't know the specific steps to make it reproducible. Often, others are in a better position than the tester to make it reproducible. http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/non-reproducible-bugs.html

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I've found that developers tend to want to ignore intermittent bugs reported by testers if the tester doesn't include extra data. "It crashes sometimes" isn't a useful bug report, after all! "It crashes sometimes, and here's the detailed application log and what I was doing at the time" gives them a chance at tracing the problem.

Comment: As a developer, I hate getting intermittent reports. If I had more time to really work out reproduction steps, it wouldn't be so bad. Usually (and my users know this) unless it's a super-important issue, all I do for intermittent bugs is increase the logging around that area of code and hope they yield some clues. In my experience, most intermittent bugs are in parts of the code not used often (if it were used more, a pattern would have emerged!) so they tend to be low priority anyway.

Comment: @Kate Paulk-Thanks for such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attempt Log in and exit the app in different ways as you can. 
Also try Adhoc type of testing to exit the app. But remember to record each and every attempt so once you caught issue could be able to attached to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to record this scenario using an addon like imacro.
Steps:
1. use fire fox, download a plugin livehttpheader - it can record all network traffic.
2. download addin imacro.
3. Now turn on httpheader and imacro.
4. perform all your action may be throughout a day or week or may be a month (probable).
5. now you've all data of ur actions.
 report this to dev, they'll have better picture about ur action and data and system config etc...